# Failing to receive JSON array in PHP sending from Android Client

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am trying to receive a json array from my PHP code..
When I am failing to receive it successfully. Below is my complete code.

already tried `utf8_encode and json_decode` but failed.

```
<?php
require_once('conn.php');
require_once('validate.php');

function fix_json( $j ){
  $j = trim( $j );
  $j = ltrim( $j, '(' );
  $j = rtrim( $j, ')' );
  $a = preg_split('#(?<!\\\\)\"#', $j );
  for( $i=0; $i < count( $a ); $i+=2 ){
    $s = $a[$i];
    $s = preg_replace('#([^\s\[\]\{\}\:\,]+):#', '"\1":', $s );
    $a[$i] = $s;
  }
  //var_dump($a);
  $j = implode( '"', $a );
  //var_dump( $j );
  return $j;
}

$json_params = file_get_contents("php://input");
$data = fix_json($json_params);

//echo json_last_error_msg();


/*$someJSON ='[{"username":"admin", "InvoiceNo":"YRH4hXzJlS", "CustomerName":"sanjay","InvDate":"23-07-2021","TotalAmount":1000,"PaidAmount":900,"BalaneAmount":100,"issync":false,"isDelete":false},{"username":"admin", "InvoiceNo":"YRH4hXzJlS", "CustomerName":"sanjay","InvDate":"23-07-2021","TotalAmount":1000,"PaidAmount":900,"BalaneAmount":100,"issync":false,"isDelete":false},{"username":"admin", "InvoiceNo":"YRH4hXzJlS", "CustomerName":"sanjay","InvDate":"23-07-2021","TotalAmount":1000,"PaidAmount":900,"BalaneAmount":100,"issync":false,"isDelete":false}]'; 
echo "\n"; 
echo fix_json($someJSON);*/


var_dump($data);

$multiQuery = "";

foreach ($data as $item) {

    $username=$item['username'];
    $InvoiceNo=$item['InvoiceNo'];
    $CustomerName=$item['CustomerName'];
    $InvDate=$item['InvDate'];
    $TotalAmount=$item['TotalAmount'];
    $PaidAmount=$item['PaidAmount'];
    $BalaneAmount=$item['BalaneAmount'];
    $issync=$item['issync'];
    $isDelete=$item['isDelete'];


    $qry="INSERT INTO `Invoice` (`Id`, `username`, `InvoiceNo`, `CustomerName`, `InvDate`, `TotalAmount`, `PaidAmount`, `BalaneAmount`, `issync`, `isDelete`) VALUES (NULL, '$username', '$InvoiceNo', '$CustomerName', '$InvDate', '$TotalAmount', '$PaidAmount', '$BalaneAmount', '$issync', '$isDelete');";

                    
    $multiQuery .= $qry;
}

  $res= mysqli_multi_query($conn, $multiQuery);
 
 if($res==true)
  $response="sucess";
  else
  $response="failed";
  echo $response;

                    
?>
```

Actual Json I am sending from Android App :

```
[{"username":"admin","InvoiceNo":"Tber0VkcH5","CustomerName":"sanjay","InvDate":"23-07-2021","TotalAmount":"100.0","PaidAmount":"100.0","BalaneAmount":"0.0","issync":"false","isDelete":"false"},{"username":"admin","InvoiceNo":"OgazVE1wTv","CustomerName":"zanjay","InvDate":"23-07-2021","TotalAmount":"1990.0","PaidAmount":"200.0","BalaneAmount":"1790.0","issync":"false","isDelete":"false"}]
```

with fix_json function I am receiving below json with a string count like string(357) which is causing error.. :

```
string(357) "'[{"username":admin,"InvoiceNo":Tber0VkcH5,"CustomerName":sanjay,"InvDate":23-07-2021,"TotalAmount":100.0,"PaidAmount":100.0,"BalaneAmount":0.0,"issync":false,"isDelete":false},{"username":admin,"InvoiceNo":OgazVE1wTv,"CustomerName":zanjay,"InvDate":23-07-2021,"TotalAmount":1990.0,"PaidAmount":200.0,"BalaneAmount":1790.0,"issync":false,"isDelete":false}]'"
failed
```

raw data which I am receiving in $json_params :

```
'[{username:admin,InvoiceNo:Tber0VkcH5,CustomerName:sanjay,InvDate:23-07-2021,TotalAmount:100.0,PaidAmount:100.0,BalaneAmount:0.0,issync:false,isDelete:false},{username:admin,InvoiceNo:OgazVE1wTv,CustomerName:zanjay,InvDate:23-07-2021,TotalAmount:1990.0,PaidAmount:200.0,BalaneAmount:1790.0,issync:false,isDelete:false}]'
```

Comment: You seem to have single quotes around the JSON string `"'[{"`

Comment: @NigelRen sir can you guide how can I remove this string count `(string(357))`from start of this output ffrom above fix_json function `string(357) "'[{"username":admin,"InvoiceNo":Tber0VkcH5,"CustomerName":sanjay,"InvDate":23-07-2021,"TotalAmount":100.0,"PaidAmount":100.0,"BalaneAmount":0.0,"issync":false,"isDelete":false},{"username":admin,"InvoiceNo":OgazVE1wTv,"CustomerName":zanjay,"InvDate":23-07-2021,"TotalAmount":1990.0,"PaidAmount":200.0,"BalaneAmount":1790.0,"issync":false,"isDelete":false}]'"
failed`

Comment: You could try `$data = trim("'", $data);`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
echo json_decode($someJSON);
```

Comment: tried but failed, I tried utf8_encode too

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, here are some guidelines : **it is not recommended** to post code-only answers, answers should provide more explanation about the code to make it the answer more useful and are more likely to attract upvotes